# React doesn't re-render on state change

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js

I basically have component as in the picture
[image][image]
where toggle changes plot view from table to graph.

Checkbox handler as follows:

```
 handleTableChange = e => {
    const plot = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({ plot });
  };
```

Logic for displaying an element is:

```
{this.state.plot ? plot : table}
```

**The issue is if I try to change the view from graph to table after I have interacted with the graph (say, isolated a trace), the state changes, but the view doesn't.**

[This gif](https://giphy.com/gifs/mPzZEkv7dIDhmBGARm) shows that at first (with plot untouched) switching works, but after plot interaction it change only occurs on second attempt to switch.

Why is that happening and how to fix it?

UPD.: **The whole code for component**

https://codepen.io/nikitaneganov/pen/JwBLoe

The  minimal example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Plot from "react-plotly.js";
import classes from "./FirstSeen.module.css";
import { instance } from "../../../axios/index";

class FirstSeen extends Component {
  state = {
    city: "Все города",
    model: "Выберите услугу",
    cities: null,
    models: null,
    mode: "cities",
    plot: true
  };
  handleFormChange = e => {
    const check = e.target.checked;
    const mode = !check ? "cities" : "models";
    this.setState({ mode });
  };
  handleTableChange = e => {
    const plot = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({ plot });
  };
  showResults = values => {
    let { city, service, model, startDate, endDate } = values;
    const cityCheck = city;
    const modelCheck = model;
    this.setState({ city, service, model, startDate, endDate });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.props.loaded && this.state.cities && this.state.models) {
      let title = "Количество новых устройств ";
      let dataForPlot = [];
      /* Here used to be some data collecting */
      const plot = (
        <div className={classes.PlotContainer}>
          <Plot
            // data = {dataForPlot}
            data={newDataForPlot}
          />
        </div>
      );
      const table = (
        <div className={classes.PlotContainer}>
          <Plot
            data={[
              {
                type: "table",
                columnwidth: [4, 1],
                header: {
                  values: headerValues
                },
                cells: {
                  values: cellValues
                }
              }
            ]}
          />
        </div>
      );
      return (
        <div className={classes.Container}>
          <div className={classes.FormContainer}>
            <Form
              className={classes.Form}
              onSubmit={this.showResults}
              initialValues={{
                city: this.state.city,
                service: "Выберите услугу",
                model: this.state.model,
                startDate: this.state.startDate, //startDateInitial,
                endDate: this.state.endDate //endDateInitial
              }}
            >
              {({ handleSubmit, submitting, values }) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <div className={classes.Controls}>
                    <div className={classes.controlsSecondRow}>
                      <div className={classes.SwitchDiv}>
                        <Field
                          name="plot"
                          className={classes.Input}
                          placeholder="Enter service type"
                        >
                          {({ input, placeholder, meta, className }) => (
                            <div className={classes.SwitchContainer}>
                              Таблица
                              <label
                                className={s.Switch + " " + classes.Switch}
                              >
                                <input
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  {...input}
                                  checked={this.state.plot === true}
                                  placeholder={placeholder}
                                  className={className}
                                  onChange={this.handleTableChange}
                                />
                                <span
                                  className={s.Slider + " " + classes.Switch}
                                />{" "}
                              </label>
                              График
                              {meta.error && meta.touched && (
                                <span>{meta.error}</span>
                              )}
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </Field>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              )}
            </Form>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.fPlot}>
            <h3 style={{ margin: "20px 0px -50px 0px", zIndex: 1000 }}>
              {title}
            </h3>
            {!this.state.plot ? table : plot}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className={classes.SpinnerWrap}>
        <Spinner />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FirstSeen);
```

Comment: Your gif is not loading.
please add the code of whole component also

Comment: Do you have any `shouldComponentUpdate` hooks, or do you update reference types when setting the state?

Comment: You need to set up  [mcve]. The code you have posted looks ok.

Comment: Share your whole code of your component plz!

Comment: @Icepickle no, I don't have `shouldComponentUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to change is the way you are binding your **checkbox** checked `this.state.plot === true`.

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   {...input}
   checked={this.state.plot}
   placeholder={placeholder}
   className={className}
   onChange={this.handleTableChange}
/>
```

Comment: Yes, I did just realize that `=== true` was unnecessary, but this doesn't actually change anything else

Comment: try debugging changing both to table  {!this.state.plot ? table : table}, just to make sure type: "table" is working fine in <Plot>

Comment: It is working, it just doesn't re-render from the first attempt. If you open that gif in post body, it shows that switching works if you don't interact with the plot.